# Configure Max Users on WCF - HTTP Binding

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

How do I configure the maximum number of users that can connect to a WCF service that is using an HTTP binding?

Comment: WCF has no concept of users; maybe sessions?

Comment: Yeah whatever you want to call it. The max number of concurrent connections that can be made to the service at a given time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ServiceThrottling` attribute in the web config.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731379.aspx